# Slack API search.messages not supporting search in specific channel

Tags: python, slack-api

I am using search.messages to retrieve messages from a specific group and user name. 
Used slacker module for it.

Code snippet:

```
slack = Slacker('token')
resp = slack.search.messages(query='test',highlight=1)
print resp.body['messages']
```

This works but fetch the result from all groups.

The documention here says add `in:channel_name, in:group_name, or in:username`. To search for messages from a specific speaker, add `from:username or from:botname.`

But adding this throws syntax error.

Error msg:

```
    resp = slack.search.messages(query='test',highlight=1,'in:my_test_channel')
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Comment: What throws a syntax error?  I'm guessing you add it to the query:  e.g.  `slack.search.messages('in:channel_name test')`

Comment: Updated above the error message

Answer (score 3):

@mgilson was already answered in the comments.

`resp = slack.search.messages(query='test in:my_test_channel',highlight=1)`